# Code in visual studio hides automatically until window is resized

Tags: visual-studio-2017

[Code hidden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXnHo.png)

As you can see in the image above this weird bug covers all the code area and remains this way until the window is resized. It is a minor bug but is frustrating. Visual studio is updated to latest version. Using VS2017 community edition.

Comment: To be honest, that looks like a graphics driver issue. Do you experience the same issue elsewhere? Or is it just in VS, whilst viewing .CS files?

Comment: @spikey_richie Elsewhere? No just visual studio. Its not limited to .cs files. It happens to any file i open in visual studio.